# How do I centre text vertically in a line in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-editors

In the current Word for Office 365, I would like to vertically align the words in a line, This image demonstrates that on the top the line is obviously above the centre:

[image]

I would like there to be space above and below the text, not only below.

Comment: Go to Page Layout and under Spacing, click the up or down arrows to adjust the distance before or after the paragraph.

Comment: @DavidPostill comment is correct and there many places in Word's controls where you can access the Spacing Before and After settings. Right click on a paragraph and choose the Paragraph Formatting control from the contextual menu. Also on the Home tab in the Paragraph group is a menu button for Line and Paragraph spacing.

Comment: a line has a baseline that texts must be drawn on, so if you want texts to be vertically aligned then use a table

Answer (score 1):

OK, there are two simple ways (that I know of) to do what you're asking. They are alluded to in the comments, but I thought I'd make it really clear.

1) *Adjust the paragraph spacing direct*

Open the `paragraph` dialogue and adjust the `spacing` before and after the paragraph to equal numbers, and make sure the box `Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style` is unchecked. This will balance out the spacing as long as the paragraph is a single line and leave you with the second of your two examples. If you are unhappy with the spacing between lines (for paragraphs that are longer) you can adjust that here as well. It will take some fine tuning though, because the paragraph spacing is in points and the line spacing is in multiples of line width (another classic Microsoft fudge...)

2) *Set the paragraph spacing to 0pt and manage the spacing within a table cell*

The alternative is to use a table cell. This is a bit awkward if you have to use it a lot, but has a bit more flexibility than option 1. Add a table with a single cell. Select the whole thing and right click on the little box that appears in the top left corner of the table. Make sure that `autofit` is set to "window". Then set the cell margins to 0cm all round and `align center left`(in the alignment section of the table layout tab). Now add your text with the paragraph settings (see option 1) set to spacing of 0pt before and after. 
You should have something that looks a bit like this (I've added a fill to the table cell so you can see it properly)
[image: example]

Once you have this, you can manage the space before and after the paragraph using a simple measurement in cm by adjusting the cell spacing (and not worrying about the paragraph spacing for the text itself.) You can now simply set the cell background to `none` and remove the table border - so neither will appear in your printed document.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This may be a very specific use case, but if you need to have: (1) an Outline level with (2) vertically centered text (3) and a filled background - try this:

1. Space below text:
   Paragraph -> Spacing -> Line spacing -> (set spacing e.g. 1.5 lines)
2. Space above text:
   Font -> Advanced -> Character spacing -> Position = Lowered, By (set amount e.g. 18pt)

I couldn't get a table to work with Outline levels, it seems like tables don't allow for Outline levels. Works in Word 2016, not sure about Word 365.